# EU data locality

Tags: privacy, european-union

Quite a few EU based customers are requesting data locality information in preparation for GDPR which becomes effective on May 25, 2018.

However as far as I can tell GDPR contains no requirements for data locality. Are there other EU or EU member state provisions becoming active in 2018 which mandate EU citizen data be stored in the EU or is this simply carryover for EU member state DPA compliance?

If a US company is already certified by Privacy Shield shouldn't any data locality issues be covered by complying with GDPR?